# Spacevim doesn't show current mode name

Tags: vim, spacevim

How do I make spacevim to display current editor mode at the left bottom corner of the screen? I want to have it done as in plain vim or spacemacs:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done via `set showmode`, this option is disabled by default in SpaceVim, and mode can be shown via colors in statusline. BTW, you can also show mode text in statusline, just add:

`vim
let g:spacevim_enable_statusline_display_mode = 1`

to your spacevim custom config. you can open spacevim config via key binding `SPC f v d`, and `SPC` is `<Space>` in normal mode.